# don't let user swipe between fragments

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android development. I have some `fragments` which are displayed in `Tab Layout`. i don't want to let users swipe between Tabs. i want users stay in first Tab. then i set a button at the bottom of the first tab and when users click on the button, then they go to second tab(next fragment).like image attached below. how i can do this?
Thank you....

[image: Screenshot of my first tab]

Answer (score 3):

Step #1: Do not use `TabLayout`.

Step #2: Do not use `ViewPager`.

Step #3: When the user clicks the button, do something to replace the contents of your initial UI with the next UI, such as executing a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: thank you. but i want show tab icons top of page. and use tablayout swiping animation...

Comment: @ehsanashtiani: "but i want show tab icons top of page" -- your users will expect to be able to navigate using those tabs. Do not show tabs unless the tabs are fully functional.

Comment: have you used "Sololearn" Application? i want implement my app like that. showing tabs top of page, send this message to user that there are more tabs too...